# How to Revert to the Original Background Color of previously Clicked Components When Clicking Another in React

Tags: reactjs

What I am trying to achieve is, as mentioned in the title, to revert the component's background color when another entry component in the sidebar gets clicked. I use React Context API for state management. The initial state contains an array of objects named `numbers` which has two elements (`id` & `number`) and `current`. On Sidebar.js, it renders the SidebarEntry component iterating the `numbers` array.
I know why I am stuck at this point. It is because there is no way that I can change the state of the previously clicked component unless it gets clicked again. The following code snippet is what I reproduced my issue.

reducer.js

```
export const initialState = {
    numbers: [
        {
            id: 1,
            number: 101
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            number: 102
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            number: 103
        },       
    ],
    current: null
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE_STATE':
            return {
                ...state,
                current: action.current
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

StateProvider.js (This wraps  in index.js with `initialState` and `reducer` arguments)

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Sidebar.js

```
const Sidebar = () => {

    const [{ numbers }] = useStateValue();

    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            {
                numbers.map(number => (
                    <SidebarEntry key={number.id} number = {number.number} />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

SidebarEntry.js

```
const SidebarEntry = ({ number }) => {

    const [{ current }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

    const changeState = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        dispatch({
            type: "CHANGE_STATE",
            current: {number}
        });
        setSelected(!selected);
    }

    return (
        <div className="sidebarEntry">
            <h3 
                className={selected && "sidebarEntry__color"}
                onClick={changeState}
            >
                {number}
            </h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SidebarEntry
```

Sidebar & SidebarEntry
[image: Sidebar & SidebarEntry]

When clicking 101, then clicking 102 (101's background color is supposed to be back to gray)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you `dispatch` a new active value in `redux`, you are actually changing the `redux state`.
But you are not changing the `current state` of the component `selected`.

I would delete this `state` altogether and do it like this:

```
const SidebarEntry = ({ number }) => {

    const [{ current }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

    const changeState = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        dispatch({
            type: "CHANGE_STATE",
            current: {number}
        });
        setSelected(!selected);
    }

    return (
        <div className="sidebarEntry">
            <h3 
                className={current === number && "sidebarEntry__color"}
                onClick={changeState}
            >
                {number}
            </h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SidebarEntry
```

This should work for you